# How to populate a nav with yaml in Jekyll that contains accordions

Tags: yaml, jekyll

I am looking for a way to build a navigation that is populated with a .yaml file.  I can iterate over the yaml to create the nav items and correct urls that also adds an active class to the nav item when you are on that particular url. I uploaded a screenshot of the existing nav
[nav getting populated with active class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnBeE.png)

my yaml file

```
nav:
  - page: Home
    url: /index.html
  - page: Getting Started
    url: /getting-started.html
  - title: Delivery
    subfolderitems:
      - page: Intro
      url: /Delivery/delivery-intro.html
      - page: Set Up
      url: /Delivery/delivery-deploy.html
      - page: Thing 3
      url: /thing3.html
  - title: Group 2
    subfolderitems:
      - page: Piece 1
      url: /piece1.html
      - page: Piece 2
      url: /piece2.html
      - page: Piece 3
      url: /piece3.html
  - title: Group 3
    subfolderitems:
    - page: Widget 1
      url: /widget1.html
    - page: Widget 2
      url: /widget2.html
    - page: Widget 3
      url: /widget3.html
```

my html file

```
<nav>
<ul id="nav-menu" class="nav nav-list">
    {% for item in site.data.static-nav.nav %}
    <li class="{% if item.url == page.url %} active-item {% endif %}">
        <a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.page }}</a>
    </li>
        {% if item.subfolderitems[0] %}
            {% for subitem in item.subfolderitems %}
            {% if subitem.url == page.url %}
                {% assign activesubitem = true %}
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        <li class="parent {% if activesubitem == true %}collapsibleListOpen{% else %}collapsibleListClosed{% endif %}">
            <div class="subtree-name">{{ item.title }}</div>
            <ul class="nav nav-list">
                {% for subitem in item.subfolderitems %}
                    <li class="{% if subitem.url == page.url %} active-item {% endif %}">
                        <a href="{{ subitem.url }}">{{ subitem.page }}</a>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</nav>
```

I am running into an issue with the subfolder items being in accordions and having the parent accordion being toggled opened when one of the subitems matches the current url and therefore being active.  Is there away to find the parent item with yaml and liquid?  I then could somehow check if a parent nav item contains an active sub item ?

Comment: I don't really get this question. You ask for finding the parent of a subitem, but you already have the `item` variable which is its parent. Is there another parent you're searching?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is stuck on this, I was able to use `{% break %}`inside the for loop to break out of the loop.  You may need a newish version of liquid to use `{% break %}`.  I then assigned a variable that will add the class to have the correct accordion be opened when you open a subpage that is within that accordion.

```
<nav>
<ul id="nav-menu" class="nav nav-list">
    {% for item in site.data.static-nav.nav %}
    <li class="{% if item.url == page.url %} active-item {% endif %}">
        <a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.page }}</a>
    </li>
    {% assign item_isOpen = false %}
        {% if item.subfolderitems[0] %}
            {% for subitem in item.subfolderitems %}
                {% if subitem.url == page.url %}
                    {% assign item_isOpen = true %}
                    {% break %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
    <li class="{% if item_isOpen == true %} parent collapsibleListOpen {% else %} parent collapsibleListClosed {% endif %}">
        <div class="subtree-name">{{ item.title }}</div>
        <ul class="nav nav-list">
            {% for subitem in item.subfolderitems %}
            <li class="{% if subitem.url == page.url %} active-item {% endif %}">
                <a href="{{ subitem.url }}">{{ subitem.page }}</a>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```